# Perform a query with MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I do something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT a,b FROM c ORDER BY a";

$query1 = "SELECT a,b FROM '".$query."' WHERE a='".$number."'";
```

Thank you very much

REAL CASE

```
$query2 = "SELECT numero,spartenza,sarrivo,opartenza,oarrivo FROM treni ORDER BY opartenza";

$query1 = "SELECT spartenza,sarrivo,opartenza,oarrivo,TIMEDIFF(oarrivo,opartenza) FROM (".$query2.") AS 'ordinata' WHERE numero = '".$id_treno."' ORDER BY opartenza";
```

Comment: That's not a safe query besides not being syntactically correct. You should use prepared statements. Some examples here http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: Just so it's clear, the OP is asking for how to perform a subquery.

Comment: I also wonder why would you use concatenation if you could go with string interpolation. Would look cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap it in parenthesis:

```
$query1 = "SELECT a,b FROM (".$query.") AS `alias` WHERE a='".$number."'";
```

Subqueries like this need to be aliased.

[MySQl Subquery Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html)

**REAL CASE**

$query = "SELECT spartenza,sarrivo,opartenza,oarrivo,TIMEDIFF(oarrivo,opartenza) FROM treni WHERE numero = '".$id_treno."' ORDER BY opartenza";

You do not need a subquery at all for this. You can `ORDER BY` a column that you aren't selecting. One suggestion though would be to alias your `TIMEDIFF` function like this sothat it will be easier to retrieve.

```
$query = "SELECT spartenza,sarrivo,opartenza,oarrivo,TIMEDIFF(oarrivo,opartenza) AS `timediff_alias` FROM treni WHERE numero = '".$id_treno."' ORDER BY opartenza";
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, just points out the mistake.

Comment: Actually it answers the question perfectly

Comment: unfortunately does not work. I get the following error:Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/viewtreni.php on line 134

Comment: That is a completely unrelated problem. Look up the documentation for the syntax of `mysqli_error()`;

Comment: sorry but alias is everything? For instance: AS 'tableh'

Comment: you can make the alias [almost] anything you want, even `'tableh'`. [MySQL Object References](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html)

Comment: @uKolka: That wasn’t the question, though. Your comment covers it :)

Comment: @ukolka You have no idea where `$name` is coming from and that has nothing to do with his question. He could be escaping it right before his small code snippet. It is unrelated. You did a fine job pointing it out in your comment.

Comment: The syntax for an alias is double-quotes, or backticks in MySQL. Single-quotes won’t work.

Comment: ogc-nick see my question in section REAL CASE for see my case because I obtain an error

Comment: @minitech Thanks. I actually didn't know that. I don't know how I've gotten by without figuring that out. I must have jsut been getting lucky.

Comment: @user2510406: In your updated code, the single-quotes are now the issue, by the way.

Comment: @user2510406 'ordinata' should be \`ordinata\` or ordinata